# how to insert image field on reply form in forum app en ruby on rails?

Tags: image, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

i try to add the image field on reply form in my new app type forum.
the app containt the principal sujet and all users connected can reply on section replie.
now , i try to add the image field more older text field.
i use carrierwave to implement the feature.

but i receives this error message in terminal:

```
    NoMethodError - undefined method `reimage_will_change!' for # 
 <Reply:0x000055cb9f2abc30>
Did you mean?  Reimage_will_change!:
  app/controllers/replies_controller.rb:8:in `create'
```

why subjection rails: reimage_will_change:

my i used "reimage" that variable field.

see complet message termianl:

```
     Started POST "/discussions/pourquoi-intel-a-t-il-du-mal-a-suivre-la-loi-de-moore-la-loi-de-moore-est-elle-morte/replies" for ::1 at 2019-07-04 10:12:20 +0000
       (1.5ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
      ↳ /home/chatln/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
    Processing by RepliesController#create as JS
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "reply"=>{"reply"=>"Amazon CEO Jeff Bezos gave this advice to those ", "reimage"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000055d560cc1150 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20190704-14120-1uwpx6n.png>, @original_filename="Capture d’écran de 2019-06-10 11-08-07.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"reply[reimage]\"; filename=\"Capture d\xE2\x80\x99\xC3\xA9cran de 2019-06-10 11-08-07.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Envoyer", "discussion_id"=>"pourquoi-intel-a-t-il-du-mal-a-suivre-la-loi-de-moore-la-loi-de-moore-est-elle-morte"}
      User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
      ↳ /home/chatln/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
      Discussion Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "discussions".* FROM "discussions" WHERE "discussions"."slug" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["slug", "pourquoi-intel-a-t-il-du-mal-a-suivre-la-loi-de-moore-la-loi-de-moore-est-elle-morte"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
####
      ↳ app/controllers/replies_controller.rb:55
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 225ms (ActiveRecord: 24.9ms)
####  

    NoMethodError - undefined method `reimage_will_change!' for #<Reply:0x00007ffb6c716fa0>
    Did you mean?  Reimage_will_change!:
      app/controllers/replies_controller.rb:8:in `create'
```

I think the error comes from line 55 of the replies controller at the level of set_discussion.

```
 def set_discussion
    @discussion = Discussion.friendly.find(params[:discussion_id])
 end
```

and replies_controller complet

```
 class RepliesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_reply, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy]
  before_action :set_discussion, only: [:create, :edit, :show, :update, :destroy]
  #before_action :find_discussions, only: [:create, :edit, :show, :update, :destroy]

  def create
    @reply = @discussion.replies.create(params[:reply].permit(:reply, :reimage, :discussion_id))
    @reply.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @reply.save
        format.html { redirect_to discussion_path(@discussion) }
        format.js # renders create.js.erb
      else
        format.html { redirect_to discussion_path(@discussion), notice: "Reponse non enregistrée, ressayer encore."}
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  def new
  end


  def destroy
    @reply = @discussion.replies.find(params[:id])
    @reply.destroy
    redirect_to discussion_path(@discussion)
  end

  def edit
    @discussion = Discussion.find(params[:discussion_id])
    @reply = @discussion.replies.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @reply = @discussion.replies.find(params[:id])
     respond_to do |format|
      if @reply.update(reply_params)
        format.html { redirect_to discussion_path(@discussion), notice: 'Reponse mise a jour...' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @reply.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  private

  def set_discussion
    @discussion = Discussion.friendly.find(params[:discussion_id])
  end


  def set_reply
    @reply = Reply.find(params[:id])
  end

  def reply_params
    params.require(:reply).permit(:reply, :reimage, :discussion_id)
  end
end
```

and model replies

```
  class Reply < ApplicationRecord
    mount_uploader :reimage, ReimageUploader

      belongs_to :discussion
      belongs_to :user
      validates :reply, presence: true

      extend FriendlyId
      friendly_id :reply, use: [:slugged, :finders]

      def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
        reply_changed?
      end    
    end
```

Comment: Did you get the result after going with the following fix?

Answer (score 0):

undefined method `x_will_change!' for # occures if you forget to add a column in your model's db table. If you have a model **Reply** and a ReimageUploader, with the uploader mounted as in the Carrierwave docs:

```
class Reply < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :reimage, ReimageUploader
end
```

Then the error will read

undefined method `reimage_will_change!' for #
To fix it add a column in a migration run the following in the console:

```
rails g migration AddReimageToUsers reimage:string
```

This will generate the following migration:

```
class AddReimageToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
  add_column :replies, :reimage, :string
  end
end
```

Migrate it to apply the change (write down the below command in the console):

```
rake db:migrate
```